# Signature of $\Phi|_{U^⊥\times U^⊥}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space with $\dim V = n$, $\Phi : V \times V \rightarrow K$ be a symmetric bilinear form with signature $(k,n-k), 0 \le k \le n $,  $U$ a subspace of $V$ and $\Phi|_{U\times U}$ has signature $(r,s)$.

What is the signature of $\Phi|_{W\times W}$ with $W := U^⊥$ ?

According to the definition in our lecture it is:

Let $ B := (v^1, ... ,v^n) $ an orthonormal basis of V relative to $\Phi$. Then

# $\{v^i \in B | \Phi (v^i,v^i) > 0 \} = k $

# $\{v^i \in B | \Phi (v^i,v^i) < 0 \} = n-k $

Let $ B' := ({v^1}', ... ,{v^n}') $ an orthonormal basis of U relative to $\Phi|_{U\times U}$. Then

# $\{{v^i}' \in B | \Phi ({v^i}',{v^i}') > 0 \} = r $

# $\{{v^i}' \in B | \Phi ({v^i}',{v^i}') < 0 \} = s $

Is it correct so far?

Furthermore we have:

$ U^⊥ = \{ v \in V | \Phi(u,v) = 0 \forall u \in U \} $

Can anyone check this and tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Signatures should add up, given the conditions stated. So the signature on $U^{\perp}$ is $(k-r, n-k-s)$.